# CTRL-C inside a container not recognized

Tags: docker, containers, sigterm

From 1 week ago, more or less, I've a problem with every docker container. Every time that I run something inside I cannot run CTRL-C to kill that task (ex. `cargo watch` for Rust, `iex -S mix` for Elxir...). The first time the signal is not recognized, the second time it kills the whole container and print a message:
`^CERRO[0477] got 3 SIGTERM/SIGINT, forcing shutdown`.

I tried to reinstall Docker but the problem is still there.

Mac OSX: 11.5.1
Docker: 3.5.2.18

Thank you all!

Comment: Same "problem" here, this is really annoying.

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich have you got a MAC? Have you checked the "gRPC Fuse for file sharing" option? In my case unchecking that option it is working...don't know if is linked

Comment: I have, and that option is enabled, going to try it out - thank you for the suggestion!